# A word for people who first see you as beneath them, and then when you achieve success, they want the rewards because now they would validate you

Tags: single-word-requests

I need an English word for the following purpose.

**1. Background**

In a private meeting between several entrepreneurs and their acquaintances, I encountered a gentleman. He was initially working on vegetable oil, and implementing his own ideas on how to run a business. Many people mocked and dismissed him. In the list of such people, were 2 young women.

Now, in the said meeting, one of the ladies say that she was aware of the recent reputation of the man's Enterprise. So she offers herself as a potential candidate for a **senior position** *without* enquiring whether such a position was available or not.

Of course the gentleman says that he doesn't want to work with her, for she was one of such people who initially thought he was beneath her. (I do not know exactly what the feud between these two are/were).

The response is the usual shaming attempt: that the gentleman need to *grow up*, that the woman was young and immature but now is "ready" and "mature" and is "good fit"...

**2. My question**

I want a word that describes people like this woman's behavior. Points that stand out to me:

- Initial rejection and dismissal
- Later attempt to - for the lack of a better term - wiggle into the man's creation
- Presenting herself as God's gift to the man, with extremely vague and unfalsifiable qualifiers
- And implying that she's something magnificent that the guy is missing out on

All of these are undertoned by her expression, that the gentleman was not in her level so far, but now he is - so her justification for her involvement is that now she's willing to grace his Enterprise with her presence in a senior level.

**3. Application in an example sentence**

- Ms. A was being ___________ (an adjective).

Or

- Ms. A was ___________ (a verb ) .

Or.

- The ________________ (a noun) behavior of Ms A knows no bounds.

The part of speech is probably not important, as it can be formed to a different part of speech.

**4. My attempt to a solution**

As one can recognize from my posts, i meet strange specimens in the world of business.

Based on my question(s) about similar behavior, I can imagine these :

1. Ms. A was **foisting** herself. But I want to know if there's a more accurate word.
2. Despite the claims of so called maturity, she's actually **mendacious**. Her **mendacity** knows no bounds. But I think this one is too broad in scope

But I'd like the experts to weigh in, please.

**5. Additional comments**

I am open to loan words from other languages.

I can assure that similar events might happen during the participation of a family estate. I can also assume that the word I am looking for may apply in both business and familial settings. I can also assume that there might be words that *only* apply in familial settings . The word I am looking for can't belong to the third category, as it needs to apply in a business setting at all costs.

**If there is not a single word, but rather a phrase or an idiom, that hits the proverbial nail more accurately, I am open to that. That might be even more interesting**.

The word or phrase or the idiom does **not** have to respect political correctness.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Ms A made a *volte-face*, did an *about-face*, an *about-turn*.

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/about-face)
> about-face:
> noun [ C ]  US (also about face)
> a complete change of opinion or behaviour:
> do an about-face
> *After being confronted by her constituents, the representative did an about-face and came out in support of the bill.*

Ms A was disingenuous:

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/disingenuous)
> Disingenuous adjective:
> lacking in candor
> giving a false appearance of simple frankness : calculating

But perhaps best of all, with the desired overtones of deception and mendacity, is that she made, did or pulled a ***switcheroo***:

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/switcheroo)
> switcheroo noun [ C ] mainly US informal:
> an unexpected change, especially one in which one thing or person is quickly or secretly exchanged for another

> [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/switcheroo)
> Switcheroo:
> an act of replacing one thing with another, especially in an unexpected or devious way

> [Oxfordlearners](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/switcheroo)
> switcheroo noun
> [usually singular] (especially North American English, informal):
> ​an act of exchanging something or changing it completely so that it is the opposite of what it was before, especially in an unexpected way
> *Meanwhile, her accomplice pulls a switcheroo, replacing the diamonds with paste-and-glass.*